# Can't receive data from intent

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I am using monodroid to make an application. In the application the user clicks a button which goes to a listview, that listview has multiple options, the user selects on option and then that option is sent back to the original class where a textview is changed to the same text as the option on the listview that was selected.

Below is the class that sends the data

```
 protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        int t = labels[position];
        String text = t + "";

        Intent send = new Intent(this, typeof(CreateVehicle));
        send.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        send.PutExtra("t", "Data from FirstActivity");
        StartActivity(send);

    }
```

Below is the receiving class:

```
protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume(); // Always call the superclass first.

        TextView tvYearChange = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvYearchange);

        string text = Intent.GetStringExtra("t") ?? "work";

        tvYearChange.SetText(text, null);

    }
```

If someone could figure out why I'm not receiving the data that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your problem correctly but I guess your Main activity is calling an activity that has a ListView and then you want the result back in the Main activity, right?

If so, the code you displayed is not the right way to do what you want. What you are looking for is to use `StartActivityForResult` and Overriding the `onActivityResult` method in your main activity.

I don't know exactly how to use Monodroid and C# but I can give you an example in Java that I am sure will help you understand how to get what you want:

Let's say my ListView activity is called **myList** and extends a ListActivity and my main activity is called **MainActivity**. Below is the OnListItemClick method of **myList**:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String text = String.valueOf(labels[position]);

    // Create the intent with the extras
    Intent send = new Intent();
    send.putExtra("text_from_list", text);

    // Set the result to OK (meaning the extras are put as expected by the caller)
    setResult(RESULT_OK, send);
      // you need this so the caller (MainActivity) knows that the user completed
      // this activity (myList) as expected (clicking on the item to return a result)
      // and didn't just leave the activity (back button)

    // Close this List Activity
    finish();
}
```

Below is the method in my **Main Activity** that calls myList:

```
private void callListActivity(){
    Intent call = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myList.class);
    startActivityForResult(call, 1);    
      // The second field is just a number to identify which activity 
      // returned a result when a result is received (you can have 
      // several calls to different activities expecting results from
      // each one of them). This number is called requestCode.
}
```

You will have to Override the `onActivityResult` in your **MainActivity** with something like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Check if the returned data came from myList (requestCode 1) and if
    // data was actually received (check if resultCode = RESULT_OK)
    if (requestCode == 1) { 
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String text = data.getStringExtra("text_from_list");
              // you have to use the same string identifier you used
              // when you put the extra in the Intent in myList

            TextView tvYearChange = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvYearchange);

            tvYearChange.setText(text);
        }
        else {
            // Do something if the Activity didn't return data
            // (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        }
    }

    // If you are expecting results from other Activities put more if
    // clauses here with the appropriate request code, for example:
    // if (requestCode == 2) {
    //     DoSomething;
    // }
    // And so on...
}
```

It shouldn't be hard to modify this Java code to C# code that you can use with Monodroid. Also, take a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) from the Android Official Documentation, they have a lot of useful stuff there.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the main activity there are edit texts, i need it so that if you go to the listview and come back the edit texts that are filled in still stay filled in

Comment: No. setResult just sets a variable in the intent saying that the activity did what it was expected to do and there are results to be collected. The trick here is that you started the List activity by using startActivityForResult, meaning that when you come back to the MainActivity the first method to be executed will be onActivityResult with the data variable being the intent you created on myList (send) and resultCode being what you set in setRestult.

Comment: If the EditTexts are modified before you call the List Activity they will remain the way they were (filled in) because you are not going to Destroy the MainActivity and therefore the onCreate() method won't be called again. Take a look at the [Android Activity LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: iF YOU upvote my question or manage to get me 15 rep i will upvote for u

Comment: I'm glad that this helped. I upvoted your question (I was gonna do it anyway, I just got 15 reputation points now too)

Comment: Im still not there but when i am i will come back to this question :)

Answer (score 0):

in Receiver Activity get data from intent as below

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
string text = intent.getStringExtra("t");
```